# convert full scrollable textview to bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, scrollview

I'm trying to convert a textview to a Bitmap
here my Xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@string/Rlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ProductListAcivity" >
<TextView
       android:id="@+id/textView1"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
       android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
       android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/bntLinLay"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:scrollbars="vertical"
       android:text="****MIMOSA**** \n Articles :\n"
       android:typeface="monospace" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

then  :

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
tv.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

but the bitmap size is the initial size of the TextView and takes only the shown part of  my Textview ,So  I tried this code with a scrallable linearLayout and it works !
 I can't find the solution .
Any suggestion please !

Comment: I don't know why you need this feature but you have to be very careful. In case your text will be very long your app will create very large bitmap. Large bitmaps consume a lot of heap memory which is limited. Your app may end up with OutOfMemoryError. Anyway, does this text contains HTML tags or is it simple text?

Comment: yes it contains simple text

Comment: I need to send the bitmap to a HelperPrint to print photo

Comment: OK. I have an idea how to solve it. I will first code it and then give you an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution for you. First I was going to get text from TextView, calculate lines and then draw it on a bitmap. It would probably work but I have tried something else and it worked well.

To enable scrollable TextView people usually do what you did, set `scrollbars:"vertical"` and set `ScrollingMovementMethod()`.

As an alternative you can simply wrap your text view inside ScrollView e.g.

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:typeface="monospace"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

then this code will work

```
tv.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap testB = Bitmap.createBitmap(tv.getDrawingCache());
```

Remove lines:

```
tv.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
tv.buildDrawingCache();
```

Now, let me explain why this works. When you request drawing cache you get cache based on the view bounds and with everything drawn within these bounds. Because your TextView match RelativeLayout and "draw" invisible text out of the bounds, you can't get all text in your bitmap.

On the other hand, when you wrap it in ScrollView, TextView size is matching the text so the caching bounds cover entire text and works nice for you.